# Earth's motion in the universe

Tags: coordinate-systems, vectors, orbital-motion, astronomy, celestial-mechanics

In the context of working with atomic clocks I have to obtain the orientation of the Earth for every given Julian date. I am trying to obtain a 3d vector summing up all of earth's motions in the universe (rotation, revolution around the sun, and revolution of solar system around galactic center) so that for every couple of seconds for a given date, I have a 3d velocity vector $Vx$, $Vy$ and $Vz$ representing the orientation of Earth at that time. However, I have to get this vector in the ECEF reference frame, which to my understanding doesn't include rotation by definition. Anyone has any idea of which reference frame I should position myself into, or how I can overcome this?

I have obtained the vector of Earth's motion around the Sun in the barycentric Earth-Moon frame and I have an idea of how to get the galactic motion in equatorial coordinates but I don't know how I can possibly combine every motion in the same reference frame, especially rotation.

Comment: "*I have to obtain the orientation of the Earth for every given Julian date.*" You don't need the velocity of the Earth for this -- just its rotation rate.